# ASCII source file checker

Tags: command-line, text-processing, documentation

For official Ubuntu documentation where the source English files are in docbook xml, there is a requirement of ASCII only characters. We use a "checker" command line (see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DocumentationTeam/SystemDocumentation/Repository/Members-Serverguide#ASCII_Policy)).

```
grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" *.xml
```

However, the command has a flaw, apparently not on all computers, it misses some lines with non-ASCII characters, potentially resulting in a false O.K. result.

Does anyone have a better suggestion for a ASCII checker command line?

Interested persons might consider to use [this file](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/amd64/install.en.txt) (text file, not a docbook xml file) as a test case. The first three lines with non ASCII characters are lines 9, 14 and 18. Lines 14 and 18 were missed in the check:

```
$ grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" install.en.txt | head -13
9:Appendix F, GNU General Public License.
330:when things go wrong. The Installation Howto can be found in Appendix A,
337:Chapter 1. Welcome to Ubuntu
359:1.1. What is Ubuntu?
394:1.1.1. Sponsorship by Canonical
402:1.2. What is Debian?
456:1.2.1. Ubuntu and Debian
461:1.2.1.1. Package selection
475:1.2.1.2. Releases
501:1.2.1.3. Development community
520:1.2.1.4. Freedom and Philosophy
534:1.2.1.5. Ubuntu and other Debian derivatives
555:1.3. What is GNU/Linux?
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to write a Python script, but the example file seems not to contain any non-UTF8 characters. I read the file as bytes and then decode them using each bytes-string line's `.decode("utf8", "strict")` method. I could not find any line that wouldn't decode this way.

Comment: ? Norepro on my side: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14954602/ (`file` being your example file, `file1` being a file containing only `àèìòù` followed by a newline). Is this GNU `grep`?

Comment: @kos: That is really interesting. I do all my work on Ubuntu servers, and mainly via ssh. I get issues on both the ssh terminal and the local terminal on both a 16.04 server and a 14.04 server. grub version 2.21-2 and 2.16-1.

Comment: @DougSmythies works finr on 14.04's 2.16-1. Perhaps you should get your file checked. What happens if you do it the way I did, `curl` piped to `grep`, to get the file directly from source?

Comment: @muru: My file is fine. I have the master file from before it was even posted to help.ubtuntu.com. I can also dump it in hex and manually observe the data. But yes, I missed that there is an issue on line 9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to look for non-ASCII characters, perhaps you should invert the search to exclude ASCII characters:

```
grep -Pn '[^\x00-\x7F]'
```

For example:

```
$ curl https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/amd64/install.en.txt -s | grep -nP '[^\x00-\x7F]' | head
9:Appendix F, GNU General Public License.
14:(codename "‘Xenial Xerus’"), for the 64-bit PC ("amd64") architecture. It also
18:━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
330:when things go wrong. The Installation Howto can be found in Appendix A,
337:Chapter 1. Welcome to Ubuntu
359:1.1. What is Ubuntu?
368:  • Ubuntu will always be free of charge, and there is no extra fee for the "
372:  • Ubuntu includes the very best in translations and accessibility
376:  • Ubuntu is shipped in stable and regular release cycles; a new release will
380:  • Ubuntu is entirely committed to the principles of open source software
```

In lines 9, 330, 337 and 359, [Unicode non-breaking space characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) are present.

---

The particular output you get maybe due to `grep`'s support for UTF-8. For a Unicode locale, some of those characters [may compare equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) to a normal ASCII character. Forcing the C locale will show the expected results in that case:

```
$ LANG=C grep -Pn '[\x80-\xFF]' install.en.txt| head
9:Appendix F, GNU General Public License.
14:(codename "‘Xenial Xerus’"), for the 64-bit PC ("amd64") architecture. It also
18:━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
330:when things go wrong. The Installation Howto can be found in Appendix A,
337:Chapter 1. Welcome to Ubuntu
359:1.1. What is Ubuntu?
368:  • Ubuntu will always be free of charge, and there is no extra fee for the "
372:  • Ubuntu includes the very best in translations and accessibility
376:  • Ubuntu is shipped in stable and regular release cycles; a new release will
380:  • Ubuntu is entirely committed to the principles of open source software

$ LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 grep -Pn '[\x80-\xFF]' install.en.txt| head
9:Appendix F, GNU General Public License.
330:when things go wrong. The Installation Howto can be found in Appendix A,
337:Chapter 1. Welcome to Ubuntu
359:1.1. What is Ubuntu?
394:1.1.1. Sponsorship by Canonical
402:1.2. What is Debian?
456:1.2.1. Ubuntu and Debian
461:1.2.1.1. Package selection
475:1.2.1.2. Releases
501:1.2.1.3. Development community
```

Comment: +1 for the right way however OP's `grep` is acting weirdly, his command [works for me](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14954602/).

Comment: Yes. That works for me.

Comment: @DougSmythies see update.

Comment: `LANG=C`: Yes of course. I have been stung by that one before. Wiki updated.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C` prefix works also.

Comment: @DougSmythies of course, since `LC_ALL` sets all the other locale variables. On that note, since you seem to have wiki editing privileges, can you fix the wiki mentioned in http://askubuntu.com/q/725855/158442? Apparently the community wiki is frozen.

Comment: @muru: I can not remember how to get to the chat thing, or I would find you there. Please know that the help.ubuntu.com/community wiki is currently under lock down, due to sustained sabotage attacks. I am not an admin on that one. The wikis at wiki.ubuntu.com have only suffered very minor sabotage, and are not under lock down. I am one of a few community members with rights to update the content of the Ubuntu Official documentation at help.ubuntu.com (not to be confused with  help.ubuntu.com/community).

Comment: @DougSmythies Ok, thanks anyway. You can get to chat by clicking on the StackExchange menu at the top, and then on `chat` next to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

You can print all non-ASCII lines of a file using my Python 3 script that I am hosting on GitHub here:

**[GitHub: ByteCommander/encoding-check](https://github.com/au-answers/encoding-check)**

You can either clone or download the entire repository or simply save the file [`encoding-check`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/au-answers/encoding-check/master/encoding-check) and make it executable using `chmod +x encoding-check`.

Then you can run it like this, with the file to check as only argument:

- **`./encoding-check FILENAME`** if it's located in your current working directory, or...
- **`/path/to/encoding-check FILENAME`** if it's located in `/path/to/`, or...
- **`encoding-check FILENAME`** if it's located in a directory that is part of the `$PATH` environment variable, i.e. `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`.

Without any optional arguments, it will print each line and its number where it found non-ASCII characters. Finally, there's a summary line that tells you how many lines the file had in total and how many of them contained non-ASCII characters.

This method is guaranteed to properly decode all ASCII characters and detect everything that is definitely not ASCII.

Here's an example run on a file containing the first 20 lines of your given `install.en.txt`:

```
$ ./encoding-check install-first20.en.txt
     9: Appendix��F, GNU General Public License.
    14: (codename "���Xenial Xerus���"), for the 64-bit PC ("amd64") architecture. It also
    18: ���������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20 lines in 'install-first20.en.txt', thereof 3 lines with non-ASCII characters.
```

But the script has some additional arguments to tweak the checked encoding and the output format. View the help and try them:

```
$ encoding-check -h
usage: encoding-check [-h] [-e ENCODING] [-s | -c | -l] [-m] [-w] [-n] [-f N]
                     [-t]
                     FILE [FILE ...]

Show all lines of a FILE containing characters that don't match the selected
ENCODING.

positional arguments:
  FILE                  the file to be examined

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -e ENCODING, --encoding ENCODING
                        file encoding to test (default 'ascii')
  -s, --summary         only print the summary
  -c, --count           only print the detected line count
  -l, --lines           only print the detected lines
  -m, --only-matching   hide files without matching lines from output
  -w, --no-warnings     hide warnings from output
  -n, --no-numbers      do not show line numbers in output
  -f N, --fit-width N   trim lines to N characters, or terminal width if N=0;
                        non-printable characters like tabs will be removed
  -t, --title           print title line above each file
```

As `--encoding`, every codec that Python 3 knows is valid. Just try one, in the worst case you get a little error message...

Comment: Sorry, It is non-ACSII I am looking for. Can "ascii" be used in your python script instead of "utf-8"? This is all my mistake, even the docs wiki as I wrote that also. If your script can be made to work, I'll add it to the serverguide master source files, as it is probably more likely that docs team members would know Python than c.

Comment: the change to "ascii" works great. Thanks. I'll edit the answer shortly.

Comment: @DougSmythies See my edit. I made the script much more flexible in its output formatting. And you can now even select the desired encoding to test for from the command-line.

Comment: Thanks very much for your hard work on this one. I did upvote your answer. I updated the wiki with @muru 's answer (sort of), but might include your script in the Ubuntu serverguide master source files scripts directory, as a general purpose solution/tool. A credit comment line will be added if it is.

Comment: Added multi-file support. Now you can do e.g. `ascii-checker -st *.xml`

Comment: When I run this as`scripts/ascii_checker.py --summary --encoding utf-8 serverguide/*/*.xml`, over 60 languages, and about 30 files per language, the output is overwhelming. However, if I run as `scripts/ascii_checker.py --summary --encoding utf-8 serverguide/*/*.xml | grep -v "thereof 0"` the output is manageable (actually none at the moment, which is good). Could I impose and ask for an additional optional argument to suppress 0 lines found printing?

Comment: @DougSmythies Done. Now you can add the `-m` option to only print the result for matching files. I also added an option to trim the maximum line length manually or automatically to your terminal width (which also removes non-printable characters like tabs). And I improved the output formatting a bit and added more checks to prevent crashes, like if you specify a directory instead of a file or don't have read permissions on it. If you want, you can suppress warnings using the new `-w` option.

Answer (score 3):

This Perl command mostly replaces that `grep` command (the thing missing being the colors):

```
perl -ne '/[\x80-\xFF]/&&print($ARGV."($.):\t^".$_)' *.xml
```

- `n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```perl
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.
- `/[\x80-\xFF]/&&print($ARGV."($.):\t^".$_)`: If the line contains a character in the range `\x80-\xFF`, prints the current file's name, the current file's line number, a `:\t^`string and the current line's content.

Output on a sample directory containing the sample file in the question and a file containing only `ààààà` and a newline character:

```
% perl -ne '/[\x80-\xFF]/&&print($ARGV."($.):\t^".$_)' file | head -n 10
file(9):    ^AppendixÂ F, GNU General Public License.
file(14):   ^(codename "â€˜Xenial Xerusâ€™"), for the 64-bit PC ("amd64") architecture. It also
file(18):   ^â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”â”
file(330):  ^when things go wrong. The Installation Howto can be found in AppendixÂ A, 
file(337):  ^ChapterÂ 1.Â Welcome to Ubuntu
file(359):  ^1.1.Â What is Ubuntu?
file(368):  ^  â€¢ Ubuntu will always be free of charge, and there is no extra fee for the "
file(372):  ^  â€¢ Ubuntu includes the very best in translations and accessibility
file(376):  ^  â€¢ Ubuntu is shipped in stable and regular release cycles; a new release will
file(380):  ^  â€¢ Ubuntu is entirely committed to the principles of open source software
% perl -ne '/[\x80-\xFF]/&&print($ARGV."($.):\t^".$_)' file1
file1(1):   ^ààààà
```

Comment: That works for me also.