# How to remove all lines containing emojis from a text file?

Tags: text-processing

I have text files in which some lines includes emojis or other non Ascii characters, like the list in this screenshot:

[image]

I need a way to remove **the whole lines** containing an emoji or more. Even the lines containing non Ascii characters would be removed but I am for the emojis in this approach.

I have seen and tried the answers on questions like this:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421709/how-do-i-find-and-remove-emojis-in-a-text-file
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266347/grep-for-emojis-in-linux
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421709/how-do-i-find-and-remove-emojis-in-a-text-file
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899423/filtering-out-emoticons-using-sed
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266347/grep-for-emojis-in-linux

But they provide answers on **how to remove the emojis**, not the ***whole line containing emojis***

Any help to `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or other `bash` based command is appreciated but a direction on how to do this with `php`, `python`, `perl` or anything else may also work.

Comment: See if [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730591/ascii-source-file-checker) helps. You want the opposite as to what I wanted, so maybe `grep -Pv '[^\x00-\x7F]'`.

Comment: If you've got a regular expression that works in a sed `s/regex/replacement/` command, then you can use that same regex in a sed `/regex/d` command